# angular2 where do i implementation for interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote a typescript interface

```
export interface MyDate {
year :number;
month:number;
day:number
}
```

I am using this in many places to group the data and bind things.  this works fine.
Now i need a method which returns some values on top of this.something like

```
getHumanReadableDate () {
return year +":" +day+ ":"+ month;
}
```

Which is the best place to put this method? I will need this at many places.

Comment: Have you thought about sharing a service ? So that you can inject it wherever you need it.

Comment: If this is an Angular app, the best (and default way) is to put this in a service.

Answer (score 1):

No. TypeScript **`Interfaces`** are not something available at runtime

You can use a class/Service

```
export class MyDate {
 year :number;
 month:number;
 day:number;
 getHumanReadableDate () {
      return year +":" +day+ ":"+ month;
 }
}
```

with typescript 1.6 and above you can do with abstract class

Comment: what about abstract class?